# How to get direct class name of instance?

Tags: android

I have supper `class A` and many child class name `A1`, `A2`, ...

I make a function use with `A` and all child class of `A`:

```
public void MyFunction(A Ainstance, ....)
```

In this function I need get direct name of instance `Ainstance` (may be A, A1, A2 ... ). I don't want use `instance of` function because I don't want modify this function when I create more child class of A.

Comment: Shouldn't `B instance of A` work for all A, A1, A2,...,An in the method above?

Comment: Example I make a BaseFragment class, and in my project there are many (ex > 20) instance is child of BaseFragment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use reflection and the class object.  `Ainstance.getClass().getName();`

Answer (score 0):

You can also make static and get the classname.whatever you access

Answer (score 0):

Ainstance.getClass().getSimpleName();

Above code will give you class name.
:)GlbMP